# How to obtain updated list of browsers in browser_changed event handler of Karma API?

Tags: api, karma-runner

I want to use the karma API to automatically close the karma server after I manually closed the browser window.

```
 ...
 var karmaServer = new karma.Server(karmaOptions, done);
 karmaServer.on('browsers_change', stopServerIfAllBrowsersAreClosed); //for a full list of events see http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/dev/public-api.html
 karmaServer.start();

function stopServerIfAllBrowsersAreClosed(browsers) {
  if (browsers.length === 0) {

    //double check since browser might only be closed temporarily due to connection issues
    setTimeout(function () {
      if (browsers.length === 0) {
         karma.stopper.stop();
      }
    }, 2000);   
 }
}
```

Will that code work as expected, because the (observable?) `browsers` argument will always be updated when the number of browser changes?

Or will the length of `browsers` always be zero if the `browser_change` event has been emitted during a connection issue?

The karma doc does not state whether the collection is observable or not:

https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/dev/public-api.html

If this does not work, do you know an alternative strategy to only stop the server after manually closing the last browser window and not for network connection issues?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the browsers array is not updated and that the "double check" does not work. I did not find a way to get the updated number of browsers.

What helped was to increase the `browserDisconnectTimeout` in karma.conf.js to avoid the unwanted closing issue.